# Set env variables in Cypress using Vite

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, cypress, vite

I'm using VueJs 3 with Vite and Cypress.

In my app I have an environment variable to define my URL:

```
const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL
```

My goal is to replace this `VITE_URL` in Cypress. I've tried to create a `cypress.env.json` file in which I wrote:

```
{
      "VITE_URL": "https://...",
}
```

but it's not working. I've also tried with `CYPRESS_URL` or `CYPRESS_VITE_URL`, but I get the same result. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. I created a `.env.testing` file that I use by specifying  `--mode testing` in the npm command that launches cypress.

This env.testing has the properties defined like:

```
'VITE_URL="http://..."'
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you added `--mode testing`? I tried using `"test": "cypress open -- --mode testing"` in my package scripts, but it fails to recognize the mode option.

Comment: I'm using "start-server-and-test" npm package:
"test": "server-test 'vite --mode testing' http://... 'cypress open...'"

Comment: @LittleMonkey is correct, make sure you use the same name in the `.env.testing` as you would in `.env.local`. So VITE_URL in both files, where `.env.testing` will overwrite the `.env.local` one

Answer (score 0):

If you've declared the value in a `cypress.env.json` file, you can reference it in code with `Cypress.env('varName');

```js
Cypress.env('VITE_URL');
```

Comment: But that will then not override variables that you would normally use in your app, e.g., those you set in env.local, will it?